# Geometry problem: Fit Triangle within 500px after border applied

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am studying drawing shapes programmatically. When I draw Triangle then the border radius is not fitting in to the `container` of the `Layer` which is used to draw the triangle shape.

**Container box size:**

> Width: 500 Height: 500

**Border width of the triangle:** 100

> values are in pixel

**How I drew triangle programmatically by using polygon:**

height = container.box.height
width = container.box.width

1. Move to point (0,0)
2. Draw Line to the point(width/2,height/2)
3. Draw Line to the point(width/2,0)
4. close the polygon. So, it'll draw the opposite line automatically.

Now, We'll get two triangle. One is **border**, Another one is **fill**

My program draws triangle perfectly but, with border the triangle box size increases more than 500x500 size. But I want to fit the triangle to `container.box`. Please see below Gif image and screenshots you can understand What I am telling. There should be formulae to solve this problem. I need to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

**Here is the image for clear understanding:**

**GIF Animation:**

[image]

**Screenshot:**

Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: This site is usually not for programming questions. You may wish to ask this on https://stackoverflow.com instead

Comment: @JoshuaWang, Got it. I need formula for solving this issue. Because It's not proramming issue. I don't know how to calculate  inner triangle across it's border. I wonder is there any formula to do. That's why created demo and posted question in this site.

Comment: What kind of formula do you need?

Comment: @JoshuaWang, Let take square 500 px. let draw equilateral triangle for the 500 px. Now, I am applying border width 100px for 500px equilateral triangle. Then what is the box size of the inner triangle? How to calculate it? =>

Comment: What kind of corners do you have on the border? Sharp? Rounded? If they are rounded, where is the center of the circle and what is its radius?

Comment: @JoshuaWang, Sharp corner like this GIF https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R6I8.gif

Note: [I wrongly type border width as border radius in this image]

Comment: After deciding how much you allow the triangle sides "width" to be you could limit the original triangle to fit into a smaller container. Another way is to create the width only in the direction internal to the container.

Comment: @Moti, Yeah thanks, Here [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3952129/863165] I written new question more brief about this problem.