# Calculate bounds of the inner rectangle of the polygon based on it's constant bounds along with border

Tags: geometry, triangles, polygons, rectangles

Yesterday I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3951344/863165) seems not clear. So, I am writing new question with mathematical terms only.

**Here is some points about shapes I used:**

- **Square:** Rectangle that all angles are 90° & all sides are equal length. So, consider **Square also a Rectangle**.
- **Triangle**: I used an equilateral triangle is a triangle in which all three sides have the same length.
- **Polygon**: A finite number of **straight line segments** connected to form a closed.

So, Here after I use the term **Polygon** to **describe triangle & rectangle shapes** when it's required to mention `consider this shape as polygone`. Becuase, I used triangle (regular polygon) to simplfy the work to find out the formula.

**Variables used in this problem:**

- **b** = Border width

Bounds of Outer Rectangle (r) that enclosing the polygon(p):

- **x** = Origin x
- **y** = Origin y
- **w** = Width
- **h** = Height

So, If `r = (x,y,w,h)` then, Bounds of Inner Rectangle that encloses the inner polygon(p1) `(r1) = (x1,y1,w1,h1)`

Here, inner polygon = Polygon by subtracting the border width.

**What is my final goal:**

I should able to calculate inner rectangle boundary of any polygon like below image, I have angles, outer rectangle bounds & border width. The problem is to find out the inner rectangle bounds across to the outer rectangle based on the polygon at that enclosed by inner rectangle.

[image]

**Problem 1:**

Consider a Polygon(p) as a shape of rectangle(r) which has width(w) is 100 & height(h) is 100. The border width of the polygon is 10. The what is the inner boundary of the rectangle that encloses the inner polygon?

> **Note:** I solved it by mind calculation(I didn't took angles in the calculation). But we can't apply this same
> formula for triangle. So, this is not solution for my problem.

[image]

**Problem 2:**

Consider the polygon (don't consider regulard) with three edges and three vertices & all angles are equal in measure.

If the rectangle(r) boundary is zero & size(w,h) is (100,87) that encloses the polygon(p) along with polygon border width as 10, then

What is the bounds of the inner rectangle(r2) that encloses the inner polygon(p2) ?

[image]

Hope I clearly explained the problem.  If anything I am missed then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[image: RectangleBounds]

Let us denote width and height of the inner rectangle as $w_\mathrm{in}$ and $h_\mathrm{in}$ respectively. Then, we have,
$$w_\mathrm{in} = w-2\sqrt{3}b. \qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad h_\mathrm{in} = h\space–\space3b.$$

Using these results, we can easily derive the coordinates of the four corners of the sought rectangle $P$, $Q$, $R$, and $S$ as given in the diagram.

Frankly, I am not sure whether these are the results you were looking for. If you have doubts you can always comment on this answer no holds barred.

Comment: Thank you so much!, Yes this is the answer exactly I am looking for solving triangle problem. I will check & let you know If an doubts. Thanks!

Comment: These are the result when applying formula `P`, `Win`, `Hin` and got result `Frame:(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 87.0)
Win: 89.04554884989668
Hin: 57.0
Inner Rect Origin: (5.477225575051661, 10.0)` and This is the result I got ploted [https://imgur.com/CRaBpPI]. Here you can see full variable border width: [https://imgur.com/2LvBVhQ],  This is the calculation screenshot: [https://imgur.com/sr1dZhp], Am I missed anything wrong?

Comment: According to my calculations, all your values, except those of $P$ and $w_{in}$, are correct. 
The correct values of $w_{in}$ is 65.3589838486 and that of $P$ is $\left(17.320508075689,10\right)$.

Comment: I was first unable to view any of your diagrams, because their link-embedding was faulty.
Since this is a comment, you cannot edit it to correct the fault. 
But, you can delete your comment and post a new comment with right embedding of those three links.
However, I manage to view your calculation screenshot. The formula you used to calculate $W_{in}$ is wrong.
The correct statement is $\mathrm{\mathbf{\color{red}{let\space win\space =\space rect.width\space -\space 2*sqrt(3)*borderWidth}}}$

Answer (score 0):

Inner triangle is the image of outer triangle under a [homothetic transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) centred at the centre of the triangle.

- The centre of the triangle is located on the altitude, at $1/3$ of its length starting from the base.
- The ratio $r$ of the homothety can be computed as the ratio of the distances from the centre to the midpoint of the bases:
  $$
  r={{1\over3}{\sqrt3\over2}100-10\over {1\over3}{\sqrt3\over2}100}=
  1-{\sqrt3\over 5}.
  $$

Inner rectangle is then the image of outer rectangle under the same homothety.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try your formula & will update